# Create a route with "search url" as parameter using Express

Tags: express

Using Express, how I can create a route such as:

- When the URL `/search?s=<SEARCH>` is invoked, answers with
  `{status:200, message:"ok", data:<SEARCH>}` if  is provided
- When not provided, the answer should be `{status:500, error:true, message:"you have to provide a search"}`.

Be sure to set the HTTP status to 500 too.

Comment: The 500 status code is reserved for internal server errors. Are you sure you want to use it? If the request is not valid you should send a 4XX error (bad request or similar)

Answer (score 0):

This code checks, if the query parameter `s` has been added and replies it as asked. If there is no query parameter named `s`, `req.query.s` will be `undefinded`. ([Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)) In this case a HTTP-500 answer is sent.

```
app.get('/search',(req,res) => {
    const search = req.query.s;

    if (typeof search != 'undefined') {
        // Search string applied
        const response = {
            status:200, message:"ok", data: search
        };

        res.send(response);
    }
    else {
        const response = {
            status:500, error:true, message: "you have to provide a search"
        };


        res.status(500);
        res.send(response);
    }
});
```

This code has the advantage, that the correct `Content-Type` header is set by express automatically. The resultant object will also be JSON formatted, it can therefore directly consumed by any client.

Please be advised, that the `500 Internal Server Error` status should not be applied to the described situation here. `404 Not found` might be a better solution.